# C# unknown type property

Tags: c#

I have a class like this:

```
public class Student
{
     private string NumberP;
     public  string Number
     {
       get{return NumberP;}
       set{NumberP=value;}
     }
}
public class School
{
     private string NameP;
     public  string Name
     {
       get{return NameP;}
       set{NameP=value;}
     }
}
```

I want to declare a Type from another class like (school or Student), but I don't know its type.

How Can I declare a property unknown type. I will set unknown type another time

```
public class MyClass
{
    public UnKnownType
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You could temporarily use `object` until you know what you want to do. Bit unclear what your issue is though.

Comment: Your are looking for how to use interfaces or an abstract class. But you must tell us more in order to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Student` and `School` types do not have any relationship between them you could use the `object` type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and use like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.SomeProperty = new Student();
```

or make the containing class [`generic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then you could use like this:

```
MyClass<Student> myClass = new MyClass<Student>();
myClass.SomeProperty = new Student();
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer.I am Making A Control.I drag it from toolbox to form.and its Constructor is empty.How Can I set T unless write code?

Comment: You can't. With generics you need to set `T` at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass
{
    private object myField = null;

    public object MyProperty
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
        set { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```